Kerberos SSO on debian apache + Microsoft AD
My goal is to setup Kerberos SSO to be able to log onto my web server without typing credentials all the time.
Environment :

Microsoft AD 2016 who is also my KDC
MSPKI
One windows 10 RDP (the one the initiates the connection to the webserver)
And the debian 12.2 server with apache 2.4 installed

To setup the Kerberos authent I installed mod_auth_gssapi, krb5-kdc, krb5-user.
Apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName zabbix.lab.kimbly
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my_private_key.key

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    
    LogLevel info ssl:debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    
    <Location />
            AuthType GSSAPI
            AuthName "Kerberos authenticated intranet with mod_auht_gssapi"
            GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
            GssapiAllowedMech krb5
            GssapiBasicAuth Off
    # Resolve remote's user into REMOTE_USER variable. Proper setting of [realms].auth_to_local in #/etc/krb5.conf is required
            GssapiLocalName On
            GssapiSSLonly On
            require valid-user
    </Location>

No special config into sites-available/default-ssl.conf
krb5.conf
    [libdefaults]
    default_realm = LAB.KIMBLY


    #kdc_timesync =  1
    #ccache_type =  4
    forwardable =  true
    dns_lookup_realm =true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

    [realms]
        LAB.KIMBLY  = {
        kdc = adlab.lab.kimbly
        admin_server = adlab.lab.kimbly
        }
    [domain_realm]
        .lab.kimbly = LAB.KIMBLY
        lab.kimbly = LAB.KIMBLY
    [logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

On my AD I created a user “web” with a SPN :
HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY
And then I created a keymap :
ktpass -princ "HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY" -mapuser web -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass PASSWORD -target "adlab.lab.kimbly" –out C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\krb5.keytab
This krb5.keytab was copied on the debian server into /etc/
The keymap file :
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
  15 01/01/1970 01:00:00 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:des-cbc-crc)
  15 01/01/1970 01:00:00 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:des-cbc-md5)
  15 01/01/1970 01:00:00 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac)
  15 01/01/1970 01:00:00 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
  15 01/01/1970 01:00:00 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
  15 27/04/2024 14:16:08 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:des-cbc-crc)
  15 27/04/2024 14:16:08 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:des-cbc-md5)
  15 27/04/2024 14:16:08 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac)
  15 27/04/2024 14:16:08 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
  15 27/04/2024 14:16:08 HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)

Klist after “kinit web”:
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: web@LAB.KIMBLY

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
27/04/2024 15:26:52  28/04/2024 01:26:52  krbtgt/LAB.KIMBLY@LAB.KIMBLY
        renew until 28/04/2024 15:26:50
root@zabbix:/etc#

Problem :
On my windows 10 RDP, I launch a connection to the webserver through EDGE, I am asked for the credentials, so I use “web” account but it does not work.
In the logs from apache I can see :
[Sat Apr 27 15:31:05.384253 2024] [auth_gssapi:error] [pid 5635] [client 192.168.254.20:54227] GSS ERROR In Negotiate Auth: gss_accept_sec_context() failed: [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Request ticket server HTTP/zabbix.lab.kimbly@LAB.KIMBLY kvno 3 not found in keytab; ticket is likely out of date)]
[Sat Apr 27 15:31:05.385189 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 5635] ssl_engine_kernel.c(415): [client 192.168.254.20:54227] AH02034: Subsequent (No.5) HTTPS request received for child 2 (server zabbix.lab.kimbly:443)

It seems like gss is trying to use a wrong keymap file. But I tried to remove everything and to rebuild apache conf, Kerberos conf and so on, but it is the same.
Do you have any leads to take a look at please ? I tried to use IA to provide some support, I followed something like 15 other guides, and I took a look at a lot of other posts but I was not able to find something relevant. I hope someone will be able to help.
Many thanks for reading my post !
What I tried :
-generating new keymap file, changing HTTP to kerberos service.
-changing the owner from root to www-data of the keymap file
-changing chmod from 400 to 777 (I know ...)
-The kinit web is working well and creates a ticket in the database
-I can see that in the event viewer of the AD :
Un ticket d’authentification Kerberos (TGT) a été demandé.
Informations sur le compte :
    Nom du compte :     HTTP
    Nom du domaine Kerberos fourni :    LAB.KIMBLY
    ID de l’utilisateur :           NULL SID
Informations sur le service :
    Nom du service :        krbtgt/LAB.KIMBLY
    ID du service :     NULL SID
Informations sur le réseau :
    Adresse du client :     192.168.254.30
    Port client :       50462
Informations supplémentaires :
    Options du ticket :     0x10
    Code de résultat :      0x6
    Type de chiffrement du ticket : 0xFFFFFFFF
    Type de pré-authentification :  -
Informations sur le certificat :
    Nom de l’émetteur du certificat :       
    Numéro de série du certificat : 
     Empreinte numérique du certificat :```     


